# How often do people use os commands in their programs?

Tags: operating-system, command

I wanted to know how normal it is to run os commands in programs, like `os.system("command")` in **Python** and `Process p=Runtime.getRuntime.exec(comm);` in **Java**.

Is it weird to do it more than 3 times?

Comment: It depends on your use case and the type of command I guess.

Comment: Every time you fork your current process, the related process copied and new one is created. If your case is portable for multi-threading, I recommend you to use threads instead using multiple processes since they are not copying the whole process. It depens on the command that you want to execute in your program, please specify the problem deeply.